# Fix Error code: ssl_error_no_cypher_overlap on Tomcat 8

Tags: tomcat, ssl, ssl-certificate, tomcat8

I have a cheap SSL certificate which I want to configure with Tomcat 8.0.26

I run this command on Linux to create keystore:

```
[root@ cert]# keytool -import -alias root -keystore tomcat.jks -trustcacerts -file AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt
Enter keystore password:
Re-enter new password:
Certificate already exists in system-wide CA keystore under alias <addtrustexternalroot>
Do you still want to add it to your own keystore? [no]:  yes
Certificate was added to keystore
[root@ cert]# keytool -import -alias intermediate1 -keystore tomcat.jks -trustcacerts -file COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt
Enter keystore password:
Certificate was added to keystore
[root@ cert]# keytool -import -alias intermediate2 -keystore tomcat.jks -trustcacerts -file COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt
Enter keystore password:
Certificate was added to keystore
[root@ cert]# keytool -import -alias tomcat -keystore tomcat.jks -trustcacerts -file www_some_domain_com.crt
Enter keystore password:
Certificate was added to keystore
[root@ip-172-31-28-148 cert]#
```

I updated server.xml

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
               keystoreFile="/opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.26/cert/tomcat.jks"
               keystorePass="pass"
               sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1.2,TLSv1.1,TLSv1"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
```

I updated web.xml to redirect SSL connections

```
<security-constraint>
      <web-resource-collection>
          <web-resource-name>Entire Application</web-resource-name>
          <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
      </web-resource-collection>
          <user-data-constraint>
          <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
          </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
```

But when I open the web page I get

An error occurred during a connection to some_domain.com:8443. Cannot communicate securely with peer: no common encryption algorithm(s). (Error code: ssl_error_no_cypher_overlap)

Do you have any idea where is my mistake? I also tried without `sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1.2,TLSv1.1,TLSv1"` but there is no result.

Comment: Run `keytool -list -v -keystore tomcat.keystore`. Do you have an entry of type `PrivateKeyEntry` NOT `trustedCertEntry` that contains your cert? If not, explain how and exactly where you generated the privatekey and the CSR that you used to obtain the cert. Your cert will only work *with that private key*. Also, practically all public CAs today require a chain cert, sometimes more than one. If the CA gave you any chain cert(s), describe them, otherwise describe the CA.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I updated the post. It turns out that procedure is different.

Comment: Your (edited) procedure looks correct for the chain certs, but you don't show anything about the privatekey. As I asked before, is the privatekey in this keystore? If not, where is it? You need *both* the privatekey *and* the (issued) cert with its chain certs.